# Prove that $\lambda_i^2=1+\lambda_i$ for $i=1,2.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $\lambda_1=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\lambda_2=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Prove that $\lambda_i^2=1+\lambda_i$ for $i=1,2$.

**Attempt:**

$\lambda_1^2=\frac{1-5}{4}=\frac{6-2\sqrt{5}}{4}$.

I don't see how this get's me anywhere. How do I proceed?

Comment: $\lambda_1^2=\cfrac{\left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)^2}{4} \ne -1\,$

Comment: @dxiv Oh, of course. It is late!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lambda_1^2=\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2=\frac{6-2\sqrt{5}}{4}=\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

And
$$1+\lambda_1=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}+1=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}+2}{2}=\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

For $\lambda_2$ do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: calculate $a=\lambda_1+\lambda_2$ and $b=\lambda_1\,\lambda_2\,$, then $\lambda_{1,2}$ must be the roots of $x^2-a x + b = 0\,$.